# Inserting lot of records into a table with Tx_id and User_ID where USER_ID is incremented with one,

Tags: mysql, sql-server, cursor, sql-scripts

There is a table with existing records with different entity ids, now need to insert records in the Table using Cursor and without hard coding the records.

Please find my script below.

DECLARE @txId varchar(50)
    Declare @UserRole_id int 
    @txId = NEWID()

```
    set @UserRole_id = (SELECT @UserRole_id = MAX(User_Role_Id) + 1 FROM USER_TB
```

INSERT INTO USER_ROLE_TB
        (User_Role_id,
         entity_Id,
         User_role_code,
         User_Role_description,
         Print_Sequence,
         Update_date,
         Tx_id,
         Add_date,
         Add_Username,
         Update_Username,
         Active_Flag)

```
     Values...
```

(@UserRole_id,entity_Id,'ACH ','AC-HEATING',7,GETUTCDATE(),@txID,GETDATE(),'30383212','30383212',1)
        (@UserRole_id,entity_Id,'BRAKE TECH','BRAKE',8,GETUTCDATE(),@txID,GETDATE(),'30383212','30383212',1)
        (@UserRole_id,Pos_entity_Id,'CASH OUT','CASH OUT TECHNICIAN',4,GETDATE(),@txID,GETDATE(),'30383212','30383212',1)

Here i have hardcoded the records what if i have to insert new records. Im not sure how do i do it.

i got to insert in these column without harding coding them and using cursor.

Not so familiar with Cursor. Please help.

Comment: I am not clear what you are asking. Are you attempting to update user_role_tb columns user_role_id and tx_id - which currently have null values and all the other columns are filled?

Comment: The User_role_id and tx_id are genrated automatically, I just want to know how do i insert the Data in User_role_tb without hard coding  the records like i have done in the above.

Comment: Data has to come from somewhere if you don't want to hardcode it - so where does it come from in your case?